# How to use classes from one project on another project in java?

Tags: java, maven, class

Basically I have two different projects, and I need to call some of these methods on class B from class A.

I've tried to make a jar of class B and to put it on the dependencies of class A, but it didn't work.

Is there a way to do this?

Edit:

Class B: Contains a FTP User utilities:

```
package br.com.consiste.FtpConnector;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

public class FTPConnection {

    public FTPClient createConnection() {

        String server = System.getenv("FTP_HOST"); 
        String user = System.getenv("FTP_USER");
        String pass = System.getenv("FTP_PASSWORD");

        int port = 21;

        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

        try {
            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            showServerReply(ftpClient);
            int replyCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
            if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode)) {
                System.out.println("Operation failed. Server reply code: " + replyCode);
            }
            boolean success = ftpClient.login(user, pass);
            showServerReply(ftpClient);
            if (!success) {
                System.out.println("Could not login to the server");
            } else {
                System.out.println("LOGGED IN SERVER");

            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Oops! Something wrong happened");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ftpClient;
    }

    private static void showServerReply(FTPClient ftpClient) {
        String[] replies = ftpClient.getReplyStrings();
        if (replies != null && replies.length > 0) {
            for (String aReply : replies) {
                System.out.println("SERVER: " + aReply);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have written these methods on other class of this same project.

Basically I want to call these methods, for example, FTPClient.getHost() or whatever, in class A.

Comment: What, exactly, did you try? How did it not work?

Comment: you should make packaging of class B as jar and add dependency in to pom.xml of A

Comment: @SparaI know this might sound like I'm not even trying, but could you tell me the steps to do it?

Comment: @azurefrog I've created the jar and putted it into the maven depencies of the other project, still can't call the methods doing this.

Comment: And your package code looks like...? If you're asking about how to use code in two projects, something which is very basic Java, then it's a good bet you didn't write the code with the correct visibility to actually be callable either. Can you show a ([mcve]) example of your class code?

Comment: Did you try to deploy or install your project before using it in maven dependencies? Clarify you question, please. Try to describe steps to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Added a code to make it clear

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro there is no package declaration in there, so: do a quick websearch for "how do I write a java package" (or similar keywords) and then read up on what is required to turn "a class" into "a usable package".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'll check how to make it a usable package thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a class of another project you can:

- import the jar containing the class using a maven dependency
- import the jar containing the class using a gradle dependency
- import the jar containing the class adding it in the classpath manually
- import the jar containing the class adding it to the existing classpath (for example the directory lib of tomcat) - Note that in this case you can't see the class from the ide, but only at runtime (it is how it works a jdbc driver for example, using the reflection)

Obviously you have to make a jar containg the class, and the class must have the right visibility modifiers.

Comment: Did it using maven dependencies.